# XUbuntu: Window manager stopped to work

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

I installed XUbuntu on my netbook and it worked like a charm for about a week.

Then, today, the *Software center* application crashed and since then the window manager stopped to work.

Thera are following symptoms:

1. Small buttons for maximizing, restoring and minimizing a window are not visible.
2. I cannot switch between the applications using `Alt-Tab`.

I almost always selected the `Save session` checkbox in the logout screen.

I tried to deselect this checkbox and restart. It didn't help - the window manager is still not working.

When I login with a guest account, everything works (but I cannot access my data from the other account easily).

I think that there is some cached data, which was not cleaned up and causes the window manager to crash at every login.

How can I fix this problem (make the aforementioned symptoms disappear) ?

Answer (score 1):

`cd ~/.cache/sessions/; rm -r *` with a subsequent relogin solved the problem.